# How to limit the number of pagination pages - PHP

Tags: php, pagination

I have this algorithm I made for pagination.

The `$array` variable is a result set from the query after the page number and limit has been set. It's a result from a PDO::fetchAll() function.

The `$array["totalCount"]` contains the count of ALL the rows in the table, not only that set but all the rows.

What I want is to limit the number of pages displayed, and make it somehow like google style pagination, I've search a lot of similar questions online, but what makes me struggle is to guess how I can implement it in my algorithm which is much different from others.

Thanks in advance.

```
public static function renderPaginationBar($obj, $params) {
    $array = $obj->getAll($params);
    $set = $params["set"];
    $perSet = $params["limit"];
    $pages = ceil((int)$array["totalCount"] / (int)$perSet);

    if($pages > 1 && $set <= $pages) {
        $query = preg_replace('/set=\d*/i', '', http_build_query($_GET));
        ?>
        <ul class="pagination">
        <?php
        if($set > 1) {
            ?>
            <li><a href="?<?php echo $query; ?>&set=1"><<< Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="?<?php echo $query; ?>&set=<?php echo ((int)$set - 1) ?>"><<</a></li>
            <?php
        }

        for($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
            $class = $set == $i ? "active" : "";
            ?>
            <li class="<?php echo $class; ?>"><a href="?<?php echo $query; ?>&set=<?php echo $i.""; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a></li>
            <?php
        }

        if($set < $pages) {
            ?>
            <li><a href="?<?php echo $query; ?>&set=<?php echo ((int)$set + 1); ?>">>></a></li>
            <li><a href="?<?php echo $query; ?>&set=<?php echo $pages; ?>">&Uacute;ltimo >>></a></li>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
       </ul>
       <?php
    }
    unset($array["totalCount"]);
    return $array;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try displaying it as a dropdown between the 'next' and 'prev' button if you want.. it would be easier to display all the page numbers..

or you can first get the value of current page, add 5 and store it as '$add' and minus 5 and store it as '$minus' then insert this in the page buttons:

```
<input type="submit" value="<?php echo $page_num;?>" <?php if($pagenum > $add || $pagenum < $minus){ echo "style='display:none'";?>>
```

it will hide the buttons that are more than 5 and less than 5 the current page

replace yor 'for' with this:

```
    $get_add = $params["set"] + 5;
    $get_minus = $params["set"] - 5;
    for($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
        $class = $set == $i ? "active" : "";
        ?>
        <li class="<?php echo $class; ?>" <?php if($i > $get_add || $i < $get_minus){ echo "style='display:none;position:absolute'";?>><a href="?<?php echo $query; ?>&set=<?php echo $i.""; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a></li>
        <?php
    }
```

Comment: I'm gonna try, still a bit confused.

Comment: how do you get the current page variable?

Comment: $params["set"] is the variable for the current page. Outside the function is set by GET

Comment: added something to my answer

Comment: Well.. It's a very interesting answer. It renders but hides the pages you wouldn't want to show. I think this is what I was looking for. May be, with some extra logic I can make it not hide the pages but not render them at all. Good job. Thank you very much.

Comment: oh youre right, silly me..why hide it if you can just leave it blank :DDDD